# Re : Joomla 2.5 | 'Global Config' > 'Server > 'From Email' address validation

Tags: joomla, configuration

I have discovered that Joomla J2.5 won't allow four or five letter 'Domain Name' type extensions in it's 'Global Configuration > Server > 'From Email' field. My Client has registered a 'Domain Name' with the five letter extension '.rockz' & Joomla won't accept it. This is stuffing up the operation of one of the components on that site.

Any ideas on how one would change Joomla's 'From Email' validation to allow four & five letter 'Domain Name' extensions ?

Cheers.

Comment: Wow, wasn't aware of this. I couldn't see if this was fixed in the changelog but have you ensured you're using the latest version of Joomla 2.5 (2.5.24) ?

Comment: OK. Installed J2.5.24 upgrade patch to J2.5.17 test site - no change, Joomla still won't allow four or five letter 'Domain Name Extensions' (Eg : '.rocks') - As such, any ideas re. changing validation ? Also, don't know much about J3, but do you know if J3 allows four or five letter 'Domain Name Extensions' ?

Cheers.